# How to use multiple antd modals in a single page by resusing a single component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd, react-component

I have created an antd table on my page. In my table rows i have given an option to edit. The edit option is basically an icon which opens up a modal with the form in it.

When the user clicks on the submit button of modal the form submits and the field is edited.

**Problem**

My problem is that if i manage the state globally using redux then on clicking one edit icon all the modals open up together of all the table rows. 
But i dont want that.I want to create a single component of modal and pass a form as a children prop and on submission of form my modal closes. 
I used CreateRef to change the state of child component but wasnt able to achieve what i want.

Comment: just share some code you have to create two components in which parent component has a table and on edit click props goes to child component and child component is ant d modal ..   if you don't get it just create two components and share that code here i'll explain you .

Answer (score 1):

I think your app dependency is like this `App` -> `Table` -> `Row`

`<Modal>` should be a separate component inside `App`, so only single `<Modal>` instance can display in the whole `App`